# Div always centered - even when scrolling page left and right

Tags: html, css

I have a simple HTML page with CSS code.

When I resize the window (from bigger to smaller) and scroll the page left and right, the text "This is working OK" stays on its position. It is fixed and works fine.

But the text "This is not working OK" will not be centered, if I scroll the page left and right. That's the main problem. This div should always, even after scrolling the page left and right, be horizontally centered and on the bottom of the page - not on the bottom of the screen.

```html
<div style="width: 1050px;
            top: 0;
            left: 50%;
            margin-left: -525px;
            position: fixed;
            z-index: 10;">
  This is working OK
</div>

<div style="white-space: nowrap;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
            margin-top: 150px;
            overflow: visible;">
  Here is text which is so long that a horizontal scrollbar will be needed for the browser window
</div>

<div style="clear: both;
            position: relative;
            overflow: hidden;
            width: 1050px;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;">
  <div style="position: relative; clear: both;">
    <div style="clear: both;
                width: auto;
                margin-left: 30px;
                margin-right: 30px;">
      This is not working OK
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So, how could I fix the code?

Comment: So what is the problem?  What does this do / not do that you need it to do / not do?

Comment: The third div is not centered horizontally after I scroll the page left or right.

Comment: <div style="text-align:center">  alone on the div3 will make it align center

Comment: what is your need can you explain it here? please leave the others which are working fine.

Comment: @xms bottom of the page will always be the screen with the code posted on the screen...are you enclosing these divs inside any other div?

Comment: That's all code. I just would like to get the last group of divs to be centred, even after I scroll the page left and right.

Comment: Do you want to wrap the text to new line on left and right scroll??

Comment: As I wrote, there is one div which has so long text that a horizontal scrollbar will be needed for the browser window. I do not want to wrap that text. And that is not the same div which has a problem.

Comment: So, I want the goup of three divs (see my original question) to be like fixed div, but not on the bottom of the window. It has be horizontally centered and on the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 0):

`text-align: center` on div3 will align the text to the center

```
<div style="text-align:center">
```

Please check the above mentioned changes in My CodePen
https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/qNRXzJ

Or see here:

```css
.centered {
    width: 1050px;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -525px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    text-align: center;
}

.longtext {
    white-space: nowrap;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 150px;
    overflow: visible;
    text-align: center;
}

.three {
    clear: both;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 1050px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.four {
    position: relative;
    clear: both;
}

.five {
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-bottom: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="centered">
This is working OK.
</div>

<div class="longtext">
Here is text which is so long that a horizontal scrollbar will be needed for the browser window.
</div>

<div class="three">
    <div class="four">
      <div class="five">
      This is not working OK. This div should always, even after scrolling the page left and right, be centered (horizontally, not vertically) and on the bottom of the page - not on the bottom of the screen.        
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: When I resize the window (from bigger to smaller) and scroll the page left and right, the text "This is working OK." stays on its position. It is fixed. But the text "This is not working OK. This div should always, even after scrolling the page left and right, be centered (horizontally, not vertically) and on the bottom of the page - not on the bottom of the screen." will not be centered, if I scroll the page left and right. That's the main problem.

Comment: @xms , so the issue is with only the first div ?

Comment: The first div is OK. The problem is the div with the following text: "This is not working OK. This div should always, even after scrolling the page left and right, be centered (horizontally, not vertically) and on the bottom of the page - not on the bottom of the screen.".

Comment: The text "This is not working OK..." is still moving if I scroll left or right, It is not centered all the time.

Comment: @xms you want the "this is not working OK" text to be fixed also?